# How to add data only after finding specific value while iterating object children recursively

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

I am trying to add tree branch to `IDictionary<int,Division>` where int is depth of object and object shown below.

Example of dictionary result:

```
0, Parent
1, Parent.Child
2, Parent.Child.Child
```

```
class Division
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }

        public Division Parent { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Division> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using recursion to iterate from root parent to child I need and at the same moment adding depth and Division to dictionary.
For iteration I am using this method.

```
       public void GetBranchFromTop(Division division, int selectedNodeId, int selectedNodeDepth, ref IDictionary<int, Division> branch)
        {
            branch.Add(selectedNodeDepth, division);

            if (division.Id == selectedNodeId)
            {               
                return;
            }

            if (division.Children != null)
            {
                foreach (var child in division.Children)
                {
                    selectedNodeDepth = selectedNodeDepth + 1;
                    GetBranchFromTop(child, selectedNodeId, selectedNodeDepth, ref branch);
                }
            }
        }
```

This method works fine when object have only one child. When there is more children adding to dictionary is impossible because of depth key is repeating.

I figured that I need to add objects to dictionary only after finding object I am searching but nothing comes to mind how can I do it recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways of doing it. First, you'll need have a separate `branch` dictionary for each tree branch - meaning for each call of `GetBranchFromTop`, like this

```
public void GetBranchFromTop(
    Division division, 
    int selectedNodeId, 
    int selectedNodeDepth, 
    ref IDictionary<int, Division> foundBranch, 
    IDictionary<int, Division> currentBranch)
{
    if(foundBranch != null){
      return; //no need to continue search if the target branch was found already
    }
    currentBranch.Add(selectedNodeDepth, division);

    if (division.Id == selectedNodeId)
    {               
       foundBranch = currentBranch;
       return;
    }

    if (division.Children != null)
    {
        var nextNodeDepth = selectedNodeDepth + 1;//note this is moved out of the loop
        foreach (var child in division.Children)
        {

            var newBranch = new Dictionary<int, Division>(currentBranch); //copy the branch for each child.
            GetBranchFromTop(child, selectedNodeId, nextNodeDepth, ref foundBranch, newBranch);
      }
   }
}
```

Note that you had an error in `selectedNodeDepth = selectedNodeDepth + 1;` - it was inside the loop, meaning it will be incremented for all the children, who are at the same  `+1` depth.

The second way where you don't need to drag all the branches around: you need to find `Division` you are looking for in the tree, say its `targetDivision`. When you've got it, build its tree branch using `Parent` links:

```
List<Division> parentsAndSelf = new List<Division>();
Division currentDivision = targetDivision;
while(currentDivision != null){
  parentsAndSelf.Add(currentDivision);
  currentDivision = currentDivision.Parent;
}
parentsAndSelf = parentsAndSelf.Reverse();
```

Now `parentsAndSelf` list will contain the desired `Parent -> Child -> Child.Child` list with target `Division` at the end. The depth will be the index of an item in the list.

Comment: Thanks for response! First approach works perfectly but without found branch null check. I am passing ``new IDictionary<>`` to method so it is always empty and not null in this case would be good check for count maybe. As for depth counter I knew about bug but decided to fix it later. Second approach isn't good for me because I need depth as parameter for further filtering.